# Gas pedal doesn't work

Tags: toyota, camry

2020 Toyota Camry le.
I just replaced the battery and starter, got it running but the gas pedal doesn't do anything. It goes into gear but doesn't rev or anything.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Why did you replace the starter and battery on a brand new car? Surely the starter is under warranty...

Comment: This car is drive by wire, which means either the gas pedal itself has quit functioning, the computer is no longer reading it, or the throttle body motor isn't responding to signals. All that said, @GdD is spot on ... *what's going on with your warranty??*

Comment: Is is possible that you may have disconnected the connector for the pedal in your repairs and neglected to re-connect it?